# Как вытащить JSON?

Tags: php, json, api

Парсер

```
$this->first_last_value = $json->result[0]->field;
```

Было

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":[{"field":data,}]}
```

Стало

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"field":data}}
```

Не берет данные в новом формате.
Как адаптировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну и запросики у вас...

```
$json->result->field;
```